# How to create a form which will add a row that contains multiple input fields onclick of a button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

How to create a form which will add a row that contains multiple input fields ( php + html) on click of a button

My row contains 1 select option and 3 input boxes.

```
<tr>
   <td>
      <select name="itemname[]" id="itemname" class="form-control" tabindex="1">
         ;
         <option value="">Select item</option>
         <?php
            $sql_item = "SELECT id, item
                        FROM food_exchange_list
                        ORDER by item ASC";
            $result_item = mysqli_query($con, $sql_item);
            if($result_item && $myrow_item = mysqli_fetch_array($result_item))
            {
                do
                {
                    $item_id = $myrow_item["id"];
                    $item_name = $myrow_item["item"];
            ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $item_id;?>"><?php echo $item_name; ?></option>
         <?php
            }
            while($myrow_item = mysqli_fetch_array($result_item));
            }
            ?>
      </select>
   </td>
   <td><input type="number" class="form-control" min="0" max="100" id="exchange" name="exchange[]" required="required" tabindex="3" onchange="compute_protien(this.value)" style="width: 80px;"></td>
   <td>60</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>60</td>
   <td>2</td>
</tr>
```

This is the code of one row. I want to add similar row on click of add row button, and I want to fetch value from database when someone selects a value from the select box and feed it in the same row using php.

Comment: Do you want to dynamically add rows at runtime? Or do you know up front how many you need and you would just like to display them?

Comment: i want to add row dynamically at runtime

Answer (score 0):

(I assume jQuery is okay based on your tags)

You can add html elements to an jQuery-object using append. You can create html objects using `$('<a>')` for an `<a></a>` tag for example.

So the following code:

```
var table = $('table#myTable'); // find the table you want to append to
var newRow = $('<tr>');    // creates a new row
newRow.append($('<td>'));  // creates and appends an empty table data element
table.append(newRow);      // appends the row to your table
```

does the basics of adding more rows to your table. Of course you also want to add your classes, names, text, etc.

---

Now, to get all options for your `<select>`-tag you have two options:

1. If you have a predetermined amount of options, you can do it offline
2. else send a request to your server

The first solution is obviously the faster one. You could simply add hidden data to your html using PHP. Either by adding a `data`-element to your table (for instance) with the bare minimum of information needed, copy an existing row (if you will always have at least one) or you could build a whole extra row, but hide it using `display: none;`.

Note: If this is inside a form, make sure that it won't be sent or at least will be ignored by the server. The easiest way to do this, is probably to add those elements outside of your form. However I would strongly recommend to use the `data` or "copy"-option in that case.

---

If you want to fetch the data live when adding a new row, you can do so utilizing [`$.get()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp). Then have your server answer with the required data.

For your example, you would send a get-request for all items. This could look like this:

```
$.get("server_link_to_get_data.php", function(data, status) {
  /* this is the callback; you should probably build your entire row here */
  $('select#whatever').append($('<option value="' + data + '">'));
}
```

(obviously that code doesn't do exactly what you want, as you will want to return an array of ids and item-names, but that works almost the same)

Then you will, of course, also need to have your server answer that get-request with the correct data. This will obviously depend on how you programmed your server. (I see that you are not using the MVC-model or similar, which I would strongly recommend)

Doing this request is probably the cleanest option, as it won't contaminate your html, however, you will also want to make it clear to your user, that you are currently processing as to avoid rage clicks. (F.i. you could disable the button before sending the request and re-enable it in the callback)

---

Summary: If you are always guaranteed to have at least one row, I would simply copy the `<option>` part of it, as that makes for a clean JS and there is no need to complicate anything. You will also only have to build your html in php and not update your JS if you change something.

If however, you do not have that, then I would probably just send a GET-request and build the row from there.